# Ionic - name of the app while watching video when screen is locked

Tags: ionic-framework

do you have any idea how to change name of the app in the video preview (when screen is locked)? Normally I changed tag name MKC and when the app is installed name of the app is also proper (as tag name referes).

But in my app i have video and audio player and when i lock the screen instead of name of my app i have “Ionic App”. I removed app from my devices, simulator, I also removed ionic cordova rm ios and added it again, but nothing helped. Any idea what can it be?

[image]

Comment: Did u try searching all files where `Ionic App` text exist?

Comment: sure, it appears nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/name-of-the-app/192539/5) did it for me.

Basically I added the following to my `app.component.ts`:

```js
// In imports
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...

// In constructor
constructor(private titleService: Title){
    this.titleService.setTitle("My App's Name");
}
```

Hope it helps